# Sorting a Warehouse-system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a system for a warehouse, and it isnt possible with my knowledge to get a good sorting system. Are there different ways and how would you solve them?

I tried to use the amount to sort them by the biggest amount to the smallest amount - but I wasnt able to get them after this step back in the list.

```
def start(x, warehouse=[]):
 'x is correct until this point'
 item_name = input("whats the name of the product?")
 item_amount = input("Whats the amount you want to buy?")
 item=item_name+"="+item_amount
 item.replace(" ", "")
 warehouse.append(item)

 decision=input("Do you want to add more items? Y/N")

 if decision=="Y":
     start(x, warehouse)
 if decision=="N":
     for x in warehouse:
         print(x)
     print("Do you want them to be sorted? Y/N")

print("The only reason for this program to exist is, to help you with your shopping list :D")
x = 0
lager = [""]
start(x, warehouse)
```

Comment: Its not exactly clear what you are asking. What is the expected output and what is the output you get? Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, the easiest would be to store all your items and amounts in a list of tuples, like this:

```
def start(warehouse=[]):
   item_name = input("whats the name of the product? ").strip()
   item_amount = input("Whats the amount you want to buy? ").strip()

   warehouse.append((item_name,int(item_amount)))

   decision=input("Do you want to add more items? (Y/N) ")

   if decision=="Y":
       start(warehouse)
   if decision=="N":
       for x in sorted(warehouse,key=lambda x:x[1]):
           print("{}={}".format(*x))
       print("Do you want them to be sorted? Y/N")
```